# malloc - invalid conversion from void* to double*

Tags: c, malloc

I want to write a function that creates a copy of a double array using pointers.
This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double* copy (double *array, int size)
{
    double *v=malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        *(v+i)=*(array+i);
    return v;
}

int main ()
{
    //double array[];
    int size;
    printf ("size= "); scanf ("%i",&size);
    double *array=malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        scanf("%f",&array[i]);
    copy(array,size);
    free(array);
}
```

I have 2 compilation errors that I can't get rid of. I get

> invalid conversion from void* to double*

when I try to allocate memory using malloc but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a C++ compiler instead of C.

Comment: How are you compiling? It sounds like you may be using a `c++` compiler

Comment: C allows `void*` pointers to be converted to/from any other pointer type. C++ requires an explicit cast.

Comment: But if you're using C++, you should either use `std::vector` or `new double[size]`.

Comment: Change the suffix of your source file from .cpp to .c and then compile it as C rather than C++.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You are using a C++ compiler.

```
double *array=malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
```

is valid in C. There is an implicit conversion from any object pointer type to `void *`.

In C++ it is not valid, there is no such implicit conversion, and you need a cast:

```
double *array= (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
```

Comment: using __.cpp__ file extension in gcc also causes `invalid conversion from void* to double*` error in above scenario

Answer (score 8):

You are compiling c code, with a c++ compiler.

When you are using a c++ compiler, you should write c++ code, so `malloc()` is not so common in c++, instead

```
double *data = new double[size];
```

would be good c++ code, if you need to `free()` the pointer, you need to

```
delete[] data;
```

You can of course use `malloc()` in c++, but it would be like this

```
double *data = static_cast<double *>(malloc(size * sizeof(double));
```

because `void *` in c++ is not converted to any pointer type automatically.

In c, however, there is no need for the cast, and in fact it makes the code unnecessarily ugly apart from hiding bugs from your program, cehck here [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495).

Comment: we can `static_cast` to and from void pointer types in c++, at least

Comment: @RedAlert isn't `reinterpret_cast` exactly equivalent to c type casts?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is a specialization of the very generic c-casting. When you use a c-style cast, the compiler picks what kind of cast to use. For instance, you can't say `reinterpret_cast<double>(6)`, but you can say `(double) 6`. Furthermore, `reinterpret_cast` cannot cast away constness, while a c-style cast can (you need `const_cast` for this in c++). In the cast of `void*`, there is technically nothing to "reinterpret", since a void pointer does not reveal what type it is pointing to.