# gcc not recognize *.C source code as valid c program

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-16.04

I accidentally assign `.C` [note to Uppercase C ] extension to my C source code in UBUNTU 16.04 LTS and open it with Gedit program to enter my codes.

gcc compiler not recognize it as a C programming source code and produce error when it try to compile.

And UBUNTU file manager show that as a cpp file.

**Code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int * c = malloc(sizeof(int));
    free(c); 
  
    return 0;   
}
```

**gcc compile command, output:**

```
$gcc test.C -o test
test.C:8:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
  int * c = malloc( sizeof(int) );
```

As we know this is a C++ specific error, and i think gcc, behave that like a C++ file as said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088025/c-malloc-invalid-conversion-from-void-to-double)
.

**This is my system info**

```
Linux ee 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP  i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

gedit - Version 3.18.3
```

I know we simply can cast the return value of `malloc()` to `(int*)` and this will obviously works.

**But** we know `malloc()` return type is `void*` see [linuxdie `malloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

And it is not true to cast type of `malloc()` in C [why not cast return of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286287/invalid-conversion-from-void-to-int-fpermissive-using-mallocsizeof)

Is only lowercase extension valid for C source code in UBUNTU, why they do this?

And how I can fix this and compile my `source.C` with gcc on my machine.

**Edit**

As [MCG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/805796/mcg) said in answers, we can force `gcc` to treat any given file as specific type which is tell to it with `-x` flag.

For example if we have a C valid source code with .f extension or even a source code without any extension on UBUNTU, by using this command it will be compiled correctly,

**Compile C source code with any extension**:

```
gcc -x c src.f -o src // with .f or any others
gcc -x c src -o src  //without extension
```

Comment: How did you run GCC?

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` (and you might force using a C++compiler, by using the caps  `C` )

Comment: You should fix it by renaming it to a lowercase `.c`. Uppercase `.C` represents C++ source by convention.

Comment: @Ryan thanks, i find out some Unix/Unix-like OS's use `.C` extension for cpp source code. [C++ code file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545080/c-code-file-extension-cc-vs-cpp/3223792#3223792)

Comment: File extension on the file has no bearing if it's a valid c file or not.

Comment: @Fredrik but my example show that gcc cant recognize my file as c code.   you can test gcc by give it a no extension file as source code for example 'f' to see what i say

Comment: It works fine, you can use whatever extension you want. myfile.myextension

Comment: I _did_ know about `.cc`, `.cxx` and `.c++`, but not `.C`. Its kinda suprise to me. Cute. Thanks, @Ryan. Ubuntu really seems irrelevant here. Otherwise I don't see the reason to downvote.

Comment: @Fredrik gcc f.my 
/usr/bin/ld:f.my: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:f.my:3: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @rfx link to answer said, that .C use for cpp source code expressed in [C++ Primer Plus](http://www.informit.com/store/c-plus-plus-primer-plus-9780321776402)

Comment: @Fredrik i also try it with cc compiler with no success

Comment: @EsmaeelE one can easily run into confusion with things of this kind, like extension `.C` for C++ sources. Especially while it doesn't look like widely used extension. Hence, methinks, the question itself ain't bad. It redirects one into right direction. Hence upvoted. However, gcc stays gcc even on gentoo. Ubuntu is not exception :) This is what I meant.

Comment: @rfx yes, i change topic from ubuntu to gcc. i dont know why they down vote it. i ask two clear question. and i provide two useful link about using `malloc()`

Comment: Give gcc the `-x c` option if it doesn't correctly  guess that your program is C.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks alot. giving `-x c` to gcc force it to behave input file as .c source (valid c source code for gcc). and this solve my second question.

Comment: Upvoted also.  I don't see why this is a bad question.

Comment: Upvoted too. Well asked, sure to be a often-faced problem.

Comment: Upvoted . Yes someone unknowingly can face this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC recognizes `.C` (capital letter) extension as C++ file.  You need to change extension of your file to `.c` (small letter). Also, you rightly mentioned and referenced that C++ requires a cast in case of malloc where as in c there is an implicit conversion from any object pointer type to void *.

See below explanation about file extensions (`.C` and `.c`) from GCC documentation. Please refer below GCC link for detail explanation for various file extensions.

> file.C
>
> C++ source code which must be preprocessed. Note that in .cxx, the last two letters must both be literally x. Likewise, .C refers to a literal capital C.
>
> file.c
>
> C source code which must be preprocessed.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Overall-Options.html

Additionally, you can give the flag `-x c` to force GCC to treat the file as C, not C++.

Comment: thanks. please add some information from your link (You can specify the input language explicitly with the -x option) and also my comment to  @MarkPlotnick, we can even compile a without extension or by any extension with gcc by give it `-x c` option.

Comment: and please require some info about this problem. As i say in comments section of post if we give to gcc a without extension file it produce `f: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. but in post question in `*.C` file case gcc actually behave it like a cpp source code. is there any flag in gcc compiler to use and show this misbehavior?